# Facebook authentication inside nodejs API

Tags: facebook, api, node.js, oauth-2.0

I'm building a nodejs API with the following requirements: my API will be consumed by Android application which will use facebook SDK to authenticate users with their facebook credentials...then, that authentication info will be sent to my API where my user will be authenticated.

Is there any tutorial/guide how this can be done...not neccessary android and nodejs, but any guide with the setup: mobile app->facebook auth->my API

Comment: Never seen one, sorry.  Maybe you'd become the first to post a blog article on it.  Happy coding!

Comment: slightly old link - might get you started http://howtonode.org/facebook-connect